# How to fix this cursor bug?

Tags: 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS today and i saw this mouse cursor ghosting problem. While moving the mouse, doesn't happen frequently though!

[image: here's the picture]

Comment: did you try to update your system by using such as `sudo apt-get update` and etc. Or does there hava other programs appear abnormal?

Comment: I did try that command. And KDE connect was acting abnormal so i deleted it but when i installed Ubuntu it was there. It's not causing any harm but it looks odd